# In MVC, how can I validate that at least one checkbox is checked with dynamically created checkboxes?

Tags: validation, model-view-controller

In my MVC project I have a page that creates a varying number of checkboxes using Html.EditorFor() and an EditorTemplate. It gets the data from the database.

There is also a string property that allows for a comment.

If any of the checkboxes are checked, the comment is required.

I have used custom validations before, but this is the first time I am trying it on a collection and I am unsure as to how to extract the collection to test whether any checkboxes are selected. (In this case whether 'IsSelected' is true.

```
public class ValidationOptionViewModel
{
    public int OptionId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompulsory { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocking { get; set; }
}


public class AnatomyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ValidationOptionViewModel> ValidationOptions { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bypass Validation Reason")]
    [BypassReasonRequiredIfNoneSelected("ValidationOptions", "BypassValidationReason", ErrorMessage = "A Bypass reason is required when bypassing validations.")]
    public string BypassValidationReason { get; set; }
}
```

The custom validation:

```
public class BypassReasonRequiredIfNoneSelected : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string[] _properties;

    public BypassReasonRequiredIfNoneSelected(params string[] properties)
    {
        _properties = properties;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (_properties == null || _properties.Length < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }


        //The below works for a string value...
        //var actionPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_properties[0]);
        //var actionValue = actionPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString();

        // What I need in pseudo-code
        // Extract the data in type List<ValidationOptionViewModel>
        // Iterate and see if any 'IsSelected' are true;
        // If any are selected, make sure BypassValidationReason has text etc...

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "atleastonerequired"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["properties"] = string.Join(",", _properties);

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

EDIT 1

Pretty much a *facepalm*. The below does the trick.

```
var actionPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_properties[0]);

List<ValidationOptionViewModel> options = actionPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as List<ValidationOptionViewModel>;
```

Comment: You need to post your answer as an answer so the question doesn't look like its unanswered.

Comment: I will do so if nobody else posts a better solution. Thanks

Comment: You still have the choice to accept any answer as the accepted answer. Your answer doesn't belong in your question.

Comment: Refer also [mvc-collectionvalidation](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-collectionvalidation)

Answer (score 0):

The below Custom Validation solves the problem.

```
public class BypassReasonRequiredIfNoneSelected : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string[] _properties;

    public BypassReasonRequiredIfNoneSelected(params string[] properties)
    {
        _properties = properties;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (_properties == null || _properties.Length < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var actionPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_properties[0]);
        List<ValidationOptionViewModel> options = actionPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as List<ValidationOptionViewModel>;

        if (options.Where(x => x.IsSelected == true).Any())
        {
            var reasonPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_properties[1]);
            string reasonValue = reasonPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) == null ? "" : reasonPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(reasonValue))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "atleastonerequired"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["properties"] = string.Join(",", _properties);

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```